# Volt: Equivalent of destroy_all?

Tags: crud, voltrb

I have a form with a "reset this collection" button. Looks kind of like this:

```
<button e-click="reset_patients">reset patients</button>
```

In my controller, I do this:

```
def reset_patients
  puts "destroying"
  store.patients.each{|p| p.destroy}
end
```

What I expect is that the clients displaying the list will show an empty list. What is actually happening is that some but not all of the items are deleted.

How is a "dump the entire collection in the trash can" operation handled on a persistent backed store (i.e.: `model :store`)? Also, is there a way to make these cascade through related collections?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't have .destroy_all yet.  Its on my short list, but I'm reworking one thing in the data provider API to make it a bit smarter.  For now you can do

```
store.patients.reverse.each(&:destroy)
```

(The .reverse is needed since your deleting array objects as you loop)

Comment: Would this kind of thing be better in a task, as you're iterating the collections? If so, would it play out sort of like this: `DeleteTask.destroy_all(store.p)` in the controller and `p.reverse.each(&:destroy)` in the task's `destroy_all` method?

Comment: I think it will be better for me to move this into the model layer, then the model can send it to a task internally when you do .destroy_all  (also, then I can make it work off of queries directly)

Comment: I hope it's atomic. The previous method of iteration has an strange effect on other clients as they are notified of each delete.

Comment: Yea, thats part of why it needs to be at the model level.  It will be atomic in the sql data provider.